# Erro armazenamento em Array em Java

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo um código onde o usuário precisa definir um vetor de tamanho N, e preenchê-lo, porém, após informar o tamanho do vetor, e informar o primeiro valor, o seguinte erro aparece:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
> at tp01.ProgramEx1.main(ProgramEx1.java:22)

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    int tamanhoVetor = 0;
    int i;
    float vet[] = new float[tamanhoVetor];
    
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Informe o tamanho do vetor desejado: ");
    tamanhoVetor = sc.nextInt();
    
    for (i = 0;i<=tamanhoVetor;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Informe o valor: ");
        vet[i] = sc.nextFloat();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você criou o array com tamanho zero. O fato de ter mudado o valor da variável `tamanhoVetor` depois não faz com que o array mude de tamanho. Sendo assim, primeiro leia o tamanho e depois crie o array:

```
int tamanhoVetor = sc.nextInt();
float vet[] = new float[tamanhoVetor];
```

Outro detalhe é que arrays são indexados em zero, ou seja, se o tamanho é N, as posições vão de 0 a N-1. Então no loop deve-se usar `<` em vez de `<=`:

```
for (i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++)
    etc...
```

---

Mas talvez nem precise guardar o tamanho:

```
float vet[] = new float[sc.nextInt()];
for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++)
    etc...
```

Repare também que não precisa declarar a variável `i` no início do código, pode fazê-lo dentro do próprio `for`. Isso deixa mais claro o escopo da mesma, indicando que ela só é usada ali naquele loop.

Comment: Problema resolvido, muito abrigado pela ajuda amigo.